# How to use a variable after it was a jquery function has run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realise similar questions have been asked before but still dont understand what is happening with my code. I want to access the variable seq outside of the jQuery function after the  user has inputed their sequence into the textarea. The console.log inside the jquesry function returns the inputed sequence but the console.log outside of the jQuery function(where I eventually want to put some other code to analyse the sequence) runs before the jquery function and returns an empty string. How can I make the code that uses the var seq only run after the submit button is clicked? Thanks!

```
var seq = "";

$("#subSeqType").on("click", function() {
  if ($("#proteinButton").is(":checked")) {
    $("#newTextArea").append("<textarea name = 'sequence' rows = '10' cols  = '80' placeholder = 'Enter Protein Sequence here' > < /textarea><br>");
  }
  if ($("#dnaButton").is(":checked")) {
    $("#newTextArea").append("<textarea name = 'sequence' rows = '10' cols  = '80' placeholder = 'Enter DNA Sequence here' > < /textarea><br>");
  }
  $("#subSeqType").remove();
  $("#newTextArea").append("<input id = 'subSeq' type='Submit'>");

  $("#subSeq").on("click", function() {
    seq = $("textarea:input[name=sequence]").val();
    console.log(seq);
  });
});

console.log("The sequence " + seq);
```

Comment: Wrap your code inside a single function, that’s the only way you can declare a variable global; tons of answers about that your right :) alternatively you can pass seq from this function to another function as well to preserve it from one to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im gonna try to explain this but you should read a little about how a code works and runs.

Lets state to types of code statement:

1. Run time code

Run time code is every line of code that run when it is loaded by the browser

2. Run when call code

Run when call code is the code that will run after an event has occured.

> Uniting this concepts:

When you create a listener, the rule that creates that listener is a run time code. But the code inside that listener will only run when called for.

---

I made a small example of this bellow, your problkem is not at changing the variable but when you are printing.

The printer button will print the var value
The cahnge calue will change that value one time

Hope this helps :)

```js
let myVar = "before";

console.log(myVar);

function myFun(){
  myVar = 'after';
}

function printer(){
  console.log(myVar);
}

console.log(myVar);
```

```html
<button onclick="myFun()">change value</button>

<button onclick="printer()">print</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide such a detailed response. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to using "click" event inside another "click" event.
An event action triggers and performs its operation and does not wait for another event inside or outside.

If you want variable value after certain operation of event, you need to assign it to variable and work when the event is triggered and operating.